# select() function don't allow printf() without "\n" in the end

Tags: c, sockets, select, io, printf

I have a problem using select(): it acts strange in my program and I can't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main()
{
char msg[1024];

fd_set readfds;
int stdi=fileno(stdin);

FD_SET(stdi, &readfds);

for (;;) {
    printf("Input: ");
    select(stdi+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (FD_ISSET(stdi, &readfds))
        {
        scanf("%s",msg);
        printf("OK\n");
        }
    }
}
```

What program behavior do you expect? Probably same as me (123 is a string I enter):

```
Input: 123
OK
```

But the real program behavior looks like this:

```
123
Input: OK
```

Let's change arguement in call printf("Input: ") to "Input: \n". What we'll get is

```
Input: 
123
OK
```

So select() function is freezing output untill next printf() ending with "\n".

What can I do to get the behavior I expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `stdout` is line-buffered, meaning output is not written until a `'\n'` is encountered. So, you need to use `fflush` after the `printf` to force the buffered data to be written to the screen.

Also, instead of doing `fileno(stdin)`, you can just use the constant `STDIN_FILENO` (which is always 0).

Comment: Man, you're awesome. Thanks a lot for such fast and  useful help! Best regards and wishes from Russia!

Answer (score 0):

fflush() flushes all the buffered data onto the associated stream. It is to enhance performance of the system, so I/O happens at bulk.