# Could someone show me an example of a custom timeout for the connect() function

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm building an application that sends requests to a server and I need to implement a way to control how long I try to connect() to the server.

I'd like to end the connect() function after ten seconds. I've read about select() and non-blocking sockets, but I don't completely understand how it works.

Could someone give me a a very simple example of how this could be done? Using C. Thanks.

Also, I'd like to add the same timeouts to the send and recv functions as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {

struct sockaddr_in server;
int sockfd;

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(atoi("80"));

fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

struct timeval tv;
fd_set writefds;

tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 500000;

FD_ZERO(&writefds);
FD_SET(sockfd, &writefds);

connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

if (errno == EINPROGRESS)
{
        printf("In progress");
}

select(sockfd+1, NULL, &writefds, NULL, &tv);
```

Can you explain why the if condition for errno does not show until after the timeout? That doesn't make sense to me. And is there any additional code I should look into here to handle this correctly. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't correct to test `errno` unless the prior system call returned -1. You need to test *all* system calls this way: `socket(), fcntl(), connect(), select()`, ...

Comment: Ok thanks. Any idea why printf statements before or after connect wont print until after the timeout has succeeded. I'm just confused by whats going on?

Comment: Because the `fcntl()` failed, which you didn't error-check, so you didn't find out, so the socket is still in blocking mode. 'OK' isn't an adequate response when someone points out a major failing in your code. You are supposed to correct and re-test.

Comment: Let me get back to you with some updated code shortly. Also, I don't believe fcntl is failing because connect immediately quits when it is included. But I'll see.

Comment: I wouldn't say not having error checking is considered a major flaw in my code, though a flaw none the less. Why do people on here always have something smart to say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168643/select-function-dont-allow-printf-without-n-in-the-end --- explains my printf problem i think

Comment: I *would* and *did* and *do* consider lack of error checking to be a major flaw in your code, and you can't just wave away having it pointed out as 'people always hav[ing] something smart to say'. You are evading the issue. This is elementary commenter programming. If you had put it in in the first place, you wouldn't have had to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than write the actual code, I'll give you an outline. (I'm assuming Linux or something similar.)

1. Create the socket.
2. Call `fcntl` on the socket fd and set the
   `O_NONBLOCK` option to make the socket nonblocking. (You may also be
   able to do this by giving the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` option on the `socket`
   call.)
3. Call `connect`. It will return immediately. It will most
   likely "fail" with the error `EINPROGRESS`, which means that the
   connect operation is in progress.
4. Call `select` or `poll` to wait
   for the socket fd to become writable. Both of those calls have a
   timeout option.
5. If the socket becomes writable (i.e., your `select` or `poll`
   doesn't time out), check the connection status by calling
   `getsockopt` to get the value of `SO_ERROR`, which will indicate
   whether the `connect` succeeded or failed by returning an error code
   or 0 on success.

You can use the same technique to time out `send`s and `recv`s as well (although for receive you need to wait for the socket to become readable).

See the following man pages for more information: socket(2), connect(2), select(2), poll(2), socket(7), getsockopt(2).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Very helpful. I'm still having some trouble completing everything, I've updated my question with some code.